# Deserialize json Object using newtonsoft json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json like

```
{"NewMessage":[{"Id":-1,"Message":"Test","MessageName":"test1"}],"OldMessage":[]}
```

and  I need to deserialize this json in to my class object.

My Class

```
public class NewMessage{
public int Id{get;set;}
public string Message{get;set;}
public string MessageName{get;set;}
}

public class OldMessage{
public int Id{get;set;}
public string Message{get;set;}
public string MessageName{get;set;}
}
```

how can we achive this by using newtonsoft.json. can anyone help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON actually contain an object which have properties of your defined classes - given the code posted, you don't have a class to deserialize into.

The first thing you can do is obvious - create a third class - `MessagePair` - which declares two properties - `NewMessage[]` and `OldMessage[]`. Then you can deserialize the JSON string like this:

```
var theMessages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessagePair>(jsonText);
```

If you don't like to create separate class, you can then deserialize into *anonymous* object like this:

```
var theMessages = new { 
    NewMessage[] NewMessages = null, 
    OldMessage[] OldMessages = null 
};

theMessages = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonText, theMessages);
```